# Is [AdDistribution] field synonymous with [Channel Type] in Bing Ads 'AdgroupPerformanceReportRequest'?

Tags: bing-ads-api

I am pulling some reporting data for my weekly reporting purpose using the Microsoft's Bing Ads API.
Following are the details:
**Report Type: 'AdGroupPerformanceReportRequest'

Fields: TimePeriod, CampaignName, AdGroupName, AdDistribution, Impressions, Clicks, Ctr, Spend, Conversions.**

I need information about the 'Campaign Type' but I don't find this field in the API documentation.      Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/reporting-service/adgroupperformancereportcolumn
 I just wanted to confirm is 'AdDistribution' can be used to get the campaign type information?                                                                                  If anybody ever faced similar situation please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The ad distribution will not help determine campaign type. You would need to use either the Campaign Management or Bulk service to fetch the campaign type.